# Why can't I save changes i do on a-frame inspector in Glitch.io

Tags: aframe, webvr, glitch-framework

I remixed an a-frame WebVR project on Glitch.
When I open the visual a-frame inspector and make changes, I was unable to save the changes. Pressing the SAVE button gives an error:

> aframe-watcher not running. This feature requires a companion service
>   running locally. npm install aframe-watcher to save changes back to
>   file. Read more at supermedium.com/aframe-watcher

I am running this on Glitch so I have nothing local.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer. I could not get it running with aframe-watcher on glitch. But with a customized aframe-inspector component it IS possible.

For an example have a look at https://aframe-glitch-server-sync.glitch.me/ and in the project code at [https://glitch.com/~aframe-glitch-server-sync](https://glitch.com/%7Eaframe-glitch-server-sync)

There you can see in `public/aframe-inspector.js` starting at line `21742` that the entire scene is serialized and sent to the server.

```
var scene = Toolbar._entity.getEntityClipboardRepresentation(AFRAME.scenes[0]);

var obj = {};
obj[location.pathname] = scene;
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

The `getEntityClipboardRepresentation` function is provided to the toolbar at line `21846`. I know, it's an ugly hack, but it works.

```
Toolbar._entity = __webpack_require__(14);
```

In `server.js` the server side handling looks like this.

```
app.post('/savePlain', (req, res) => {
    var before = '<html><head><script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script></head><body>';
    var after = '</body></html>';
    for (const [filepath, content] of Object.entries(req.body)) {
        fs.writeFileSync('./public' + filepath, before + content + after);
    }
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

I hope this example can be a good start for further experiments. :)

Answer (score 0):

The inspector cannot modify files on the server side. When using the [aframe watcher](https://github.com/supermedium/aframe-watcher) the inspector can edit and save changes on a scene in your local machine.

Comment: You can, however, copy and paste the a-entity they give.